# Problem with chapters in Latex

Tags: appendix

[image]

Chapters are numbered numerically at the beginning and then alphabetically. I've tried using the appendix function, but that doesn't work properly with subsequent chapters. How to solve this? First screenshoot is my result, second is result I would like to reach.

Code:
\appendix\chapter{A}
\appendix\chapter{B}
\appendix\chapter{C}
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `\appendix` command *once* before the first appendix. After the `\appendix` command appears, all chapters (in a `book` or `report`-like class) will be treated as appendices. Because you did `\appendix` before each chapter, it reset the appendix number back to 1 (printed as A) for each `\chapter`.

Comment: Thank You, it works!,